# extglob negation not working as expected

Tags: bash, command-line, wildcards

I was trying to use negation to exclude directories from globbing, but directories still appear in pattern match:

```
bash-4.3$ ls
file_1.txt  testdir
bash-4.3$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
bash-4.3$ echo !(*/)
file_1.txt testdir
bash-4.3$
```

What exactly am I doing wrong ?

Note:I know I can use `for` loop with `[` or `find` command, but I'm trying to figure out `extglob` specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a `/` in the `@(...)`, `!(...)`, `*(...)`...

The `/` can only appear between globs, even `a[x/y]b` is treated as `@(a\[x)/@(y\]b)`. globs are first split on `/` and each part matched against the content of a directory. When there are `x(...)` ksh glob extensions, however, there's no splitting on the `/` that are inside the `(...)`, but each glob part is still matched against file names. In `!(*/*)`, `*/*` is matched against each file name in the current directory. Obviously, no file name may ever contain a `/`, so it matches nothing, so `!(*/*)` matches every file.

Here, you'd want to use `zsh` and its glob qualifiers:

```
echo *(^/)
```

For the files of any type except directory. Or to be the opposite of `bash`'s `*/` (which is any file of type directory *after symlink resolution*):

```
echo *(-^/)
```

(files that are neither directories nor symlinks to directories).

Comment: So, in short there's no way to filter out directories using `extglob`, right ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Right. Bash can only filter files by name, not by type, except for a trailing `/` but that can only be a trailing `/`, it can't be nested inside anything.